# How can I access to loss value in Keras LSTM implementation?

Tags: keras, lstm, loss-function

I use Keras library and it's LSTM model. When I train my network I can see `loss` value in my program execution console. I like to know how can I access to this value in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access it by assigning a variable when calling fit

```
hist = model.fit(X, y)
```

Where hist is a dictionary containing history of various variables during training. To get your training loss you would do `hist['loss']`

Comment: Do you know how can I access to the last loss value? using `hist['loss']` gives me an array with the same length with iteration number.

Comment: It is a numpy array, accessing the last index is done by: last_loss = hist['loss'][-1]. -1 stands for the last index in the array, -2 would be the second to last.. and so on.

Comment: @SimonLarsson how do I get also de validation loss, keeping the loss too?.

Comment: Do something like `model.fit(X, Y, validation_split=0.2)` and then `hist['val_loss']` to access it